# Пропадают фрагменты внутри TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

Проблема такова. Есть приложение с NavigationDrawer в нем есть несколько пунктов меню. В первом из них есть Tabы.Так вот, при первом включении всё работает нормально и отображается корректно. При переключении в NavigationDrawer на инной пункт меню и возврате на первый, фрагменты в табах перестают отображатся и табы перестают нормально переключатся, сдвигаются ровно настолько, насколько сдвинулся и палец. Заранее спасибо за ответ:)

Content.java

```
    package com.example.kombo.eplog.fragments;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.kombo.eplog.R;

import static com.example.kombo.eplog.R.id.pager;


public class MusContent extends Fragment {

    private int COUNT_OF_TABS=2;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    public MusContent() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mus_content, container, false);
        View content=(View) container.getParent();

        appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout)content.findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        tabLayout=new TabLayout(getActivity());
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        appBarLayout.addView(tabLayout);

        viewPager=(ViewPager) root.findViewById(pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(COUNT_OF_TABS+1);
        VpAdapter pagerAdapter=new VpAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        appBarLayout.removeView(tabLayout);
        viewPager=null;


    }

    public class VpAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public VpAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0: return new FragmentMusic();
                case 1: return new FragmentAlbums();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return COUNT_OF_TABS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: return getResources().getString(R.string.music_str);
                case 1: return getResources().getString(R.string.albums_str);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

fragment_viewpager.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab_container"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.fragments.MusContent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Нормально работает

[image: Нормально работает]

Ненормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как используете Fragment необходимо передавать в адаптер getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное :)))

Comment: Большое очень большое вам спасибо! Я с этим мучался 2 дня не мог понять в чём проблема адаптер, ViewPager и TabLayout писал вроде правильно по документации, смотрел ролики на YouTube, но не понимал ничего в итоге я нашёл ваш ответ и я понял что код у меня был написан правильно только вот из-за этого момента всё было неправильно. Ещё раз спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы не используете сохранения состояния фрагмента и фрагментов всего 2, то можно как альтернативу использовать [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) вместо [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). Первый не уничтожает фрагмент а лишь уничтожает его представление а сам фрагмент существует в `FragmentManager`, второй уничтожает фрагменты и сохраняет обьект `Bundle`.

Comment: Ок Спасибо) А каким образом вытащить его из Bundle?

Comment: @Serhiy, фрагменты пропадают с `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: И как же вытащит всё это дело из Bundle?

Comment: Пока не пробывал

Comment: @Serhiy, при использовании `FragmentPagerAdapter` фрагмент только attach/detach и не сохраняет свое состояние в Bundle.

Comment: Спасибо) Буду пробывать